# Шукаємо вдалий переклад терміну Requirements Traceability Matrix

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

"Перекладаємо PMBOK Lexicon та ISO Vocabulary в рамках проєкту ""PMBOK та PM ISO українською"". Намагаємося підбирати прості переклади, але такі, що передають сенс оригінальних англійських термінів.

Наш варіант:

- Матриця простежуваності вимог

Чи це корректний та граматично правильний переклад?

Визначення терміну Requirements Traceability Matrix [там][1] таке:

> **Requirements Traceability Matrix.** A grid that links product requirements from their origin to the deliverables that satisfy them.

[1]: https://wiki.friendsofcnm.org/en/Requirements_Traceability_Matrix
"

Comment: Раджу прочитати оцю статтю - [ПРОЦЕСОВІ ПРИКМЕТНИКИ В НАУКОВІЙ МОВІ](https://r2u.org.ua/node/162).

Answer (score 1):

- Матриця простежності вимог.

*Простежність* утворив за аналогією з *[перевірність](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).* І виявляється, що таке слово вже є у [словнику](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=traceability&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on):

> **traceability** **1.** відсте́жність, просте́жність **2.** трасо́вність